# Showing image in ImageView after capturing (android java)

Tags: java, android, camera

My app has to make a picture, and show it in an imageview. I got this to work, but out of the blue it doesn't anymore.

This is my code for the button:

```
public void makeFoto(View v) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), (subject.getText().toString() + cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        file.delete();
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(photoIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST);
}
```

This is in my onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch(requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST:
            Uri img = capturedImageUri;
            imv.setImageURI(img);
        case CHOOSE_PHOTO_REQUEST:
            try {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imv.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I have two results, one for taking pic and one for choosing pic from gallery.
this is the error I get:

```
    04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.icomplain/com.example.icomplain.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3019)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1176)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.example.icomplain.Home.onActivityResult(Home.java:154)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2972)
04-03 18:16:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     ... 11 more
04-03 18:16:31.478: I/Process(1478): Sending signal. PID: 1478 SIG: 9
04-03 18:17:36.507: D/dalvikvm(1539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 2% free 14131K/14339K, paused 42ms
04-03 18:17:36.507: I/dalvikvm-heap(1539): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.868MB for 1048592-byte allocation
04-03 18:17:36.597: D/dalvikvm(1539): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 15154K/15431K, paused 4ms+3ms
04-03 18:17:36.667: D/dalvikvm(1539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 15154K/15431K, paused 26ms
04-03 18:17:36.677: I/dalvikvm-heap(1539): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.646MB for 1865972-byte allocation
04-03 18:17:36.727: D/dalvikvm(1539): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 16976K/17287K, paused 4ms+3ms
```

Image from log can be view [here](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/1920/schermafbeelding2013040ei.png).

Comment: Can you log whats the value of captured imageUri?

Comment: I think you are getting URI null

Comment: log uploaded...
So what should i change if the URI is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I guess you need `break;` before `case CHOOSE_PHOTO_REQUEST:`.
2. It's an optional but unfortunately, determining the output filename is completely depending on what camera app has installed on the device or chosen by user, even it specified on `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`. So you should see `data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)` and `data.getData()` in addition to `capturedImageUri`.